# Div tag reading inline stlyes and editing a value alone using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple `<div>` div tag in which i need to find a div by using a class name and need to read the inline style `(Width:150;height:150:top:10)` and need to increase the width size alone without affecting the others inline styles.

```
<html>
<div id="tempDiv">
<div style="width: 61px; height: 55px; padding-top: 25px; display: none;" class="choice_box">Test 1</div>
<div style="width: 61px; height: 55px; padding-top: 25px;" class="choice_box">Test 2</div>
<div style="width: 61px; height: 65px; padding-top: 15px;"class="choice_box">Test 3</div>
<div style="width: 61px; height: 55px; padding-top: 25px;" class="choice_box">Test 4</div>
</div>
</html>
```

By using the `tempDiv` id i need to find the class:Choice_box and need to change the width alone.

Please explain how can I do this?

I tried this code but the length is returning 0 :

```
$(function(){
    var findme = $('#tempDiv.choice_box')

    alert(findme.length);

});
```

Comment: Absolutely. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code that you tried

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/tEzvs/)

```
<!-- sample markup -->
<div>
    <div class="findme" style="width:100px;height:100px;top:10px">Find me</div>
    <div>do not find me</div>
</div>


$(function(){
   var findme = $('div.findme');
    findme.css({width:'200px'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var findme = $('#tempDiv.choice_box')

    alert(findme.length);

});
```

> I tried this code but the length is returning 0 :

Of course, it would return 0. Because with this selector (`#tempDiv.choice_box`), you are trying to find an element with an id of `tempDiv` and having a class of `choice_box`. But what you should be doing is finding the descendants, with class `choice_box`, of element with id of `tempDiv`. So, your selector should be:

```
$('#tempDiv .choice_box') // notice the space
```

Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/N6d38/) I put together.